# What does "coming in the front" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, definition

From the "Repo men" movie (2010).

In the future humans have extended and improved our lives through highly sophisticated and expensive mechanical organs created by a company called "The Union". But there are the Repo Men who take the organs back if the clients are in arrears which causes their death.

The main character, one of the Repo men, comes to work and sees how a manager tries to assure another client to buy an organ mentioning that Repo men are almost never utilized. After that the manager tells the mail character this:

> You're killing me, coming in the front like that. l got guys trying to make sales out there, l don't need you on the floor spooking clients, all right? We want them buying, not thinking.

What does "coming in the front" mean?

Comment: To come in the front here means: to come in the front door or entrance of a business or shop or store. The typical expressions in AmE are: to come in (through) the front or in (through) the back. It refers to how one enters a building, house, store etc. There are back entrances and front entrances.

Answer (score 2):

Coming in the front here means: to come in the front door or entrance of a business or shop or store. The typical expressions in AmE are: to come in (through) the front or (through) the back. It refers to how one enters a building, house, store etc. There are back entrances and front entrances.

**The grammar** of /Coming in/ through the front [door]/ is a gerund used as a noun just like: playing games in the garden, for example. **It is the subject of the sentence**.

Another example: /Coming in/ through the front [door of a house] is not always the best way to come into house from the garage.

Going out the back-door is what my parents want me to do. They don't want me going out the back [door of the house].

Answer (score 0):

The character is telling the "Repo Man" not to come in through the *front* of the office, where they are selling to customers.  Instead they should use the back entrance, where potential customers can't see them.

The movie "Repo Man" is science fiction, but as with most stories it's based on real life.  "Repo" is short for ["repossession"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repossession) -- there are real "repo men" who will take back a car (or any expensive and resealable item) when the buyer falls seriously behind on their financing.

Usually repo men work with already unscrupulous sellers who offer some kind of private financing.  For example, a [disreputable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disreputable) used car dealer wouldn't want to scare off a potential buyer who sees that the dealer employs large, tough-looking men who will "repossess" the car if the buyer fails to make his payments.